# getting error in path line, . guide please

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

I am training my system for texture analysis, using local binary pattern. here I am training images. taken code from somewhere. I am getting the error in defining the path of images.

```
# OpenCV bindings
import cv2
# To performing path manipulations 
import os
# Local Binary Pattern function
from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern
# To calculate a normalized histogram 
from scipy.stats import itemfreq
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
# Utility package -- use pip install cvutils to install
import cvutils
# To read class from file
import csv

#Store the path of training images in train_images
train_images = cvutils.imlist ("'C:\Users\Babar\MATLAB\isp\training 
images\fire-image1.jpg',
'C:\Users\Babar\MATLAB\isp\training images\fire-image2.jpg',
'C:\Users\Babar\MATLAB\isp\training images\fire-image3.jpg'")
# Dictionary containing image paths as keys and corresponding label as 
value
train_dic = {'fire-image1':0,'fire-image2':0,'fire-image3':0}
with open('C:\Users\Babar\MATLAB\isp\class_train.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:
    train_dic[row[0]] = int(row[1])
```

Comment: Firstly post your code as text, not a link to an image. Secondly you need to use double `"` or single quotes `'` not both, thirdly your back slashes need to be escaped: `'\\'` or you prefix your string `'r'` so it becomes a raw string

Comment: thanks, corrected.
but now getting error while debugging is '' imlist() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given''

Comment: I've never used `cvutils` but can you try passing a list of strings, and additionally which line throws the error? Try prefixing all your file paths with `'r'` so `r'C:\Users\Babar\MATLAB\isp\training 
images\fire-image1.jpg'` and so on

Comment: [Here](http://hanzratech.in/2015/05/30/local-binary-patterns.html) is an example. The `cvutils.imlist()` should store the path for testing images. Try to use `'C:\\Users\\Babar\MATLAB\\isp\\training images\\'`.

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski respected sir i have corrected this. but now getting error while debugging is '' imlist() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given''

Comment: Did you try this: `cvutils.imlist('C:\\Users\\Babar\MATLAB\\isp\\training images\\)`? Only one argument which is a path to the traning dir?

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski done sir, getting this error now in last line. Error('iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)')

Comment: @EdChum done sir, getting this error now in last line. Error('iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)')